# Where are the manuals for debconf specific commands?

Tags: linux, debian, dpkg, debian-installer, debconf

I'm currently creating a custom live-image installer. Anyways, I'm taking a look at all other packages in the binary stage and many (if not all) are using debconf to show progress bars and take inputs, etc.

My problem is none of the [debconf](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/debconf/index.html) manuals states about commands like `db_progress` nor are there any helpful information in `/usr/share/debconf/confmodule`.

Not even a google search with quotes ["debconf" "db_progress"] would lead me to any valid information.

Where do I find them?

Comment: Can someone explain to me why this was downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `debconf` commands are supposed to be described in `man debconf-devel` (look at it on your system, the online version is poorly-formatted), but `db_progress` isn’t mentioned there.

As far as I can tell, the only description of progress-bar handling is in [`Debconf::ConfModule`](https://salsa.debian.org/pkg-debconf/debconf/-/blob/master/Debconf/ConfModule.pm). You can see it in use in [the demo sample](https://salsa.debian.org/pkg-debconf/debconf/-/blob/master/samples/demo).

Comment: Thank you for the demo sample. I wonder what the Debian developers response to this? Are people just suppose to "know" these things? Is it just me being a terrible dev?

Comment: My answer was written with my Debian Developer hat on ;-). Searching [in the Debian source code](https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=\bdb_progress\b&literal=0) suggests that `db_progress` is mostly used in the installer, and I suspect people working on the installer are familiar with it (or find out about it from reading the code of other installation modules). This isn’t just you being a terrible dev, it took me some research to figure out enough to write my answer... (At some point I’ll probably suggest a patch to the docs.)

Comment: Thank you Stephen. I too took some time before posting my question but I had no luck... Again, thank you for the answer you provided. I'd personally like to stay in touch since I'd like to more about Debian and it's community. Idk if that's something I'm allowed to say here...